# Running PHP on a Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I am very new to web development and I have decided to learn the ropes of php with `mysql`. I am currently taking an online course from Lynda.com teaching me on concepts of `php` and `mysql`.
I have installed the `WAMP` server on windows 2008 box and I can start all the `apache services` and when I go to `http://localhost` it opens up the `WAMP` webpage and when I  click on `phpinfo()` it takes me to my php page showing me the version (5.5.12)

I have also configured `IIS` using [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) but no luck when I open my php file I get the source code display in my internet explorer with all  the html formatting. Its just a simple "hello world" file and the file extension is `*.php`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know where I was going wrong.. I had created folder on my desktop and then saved the php file in it and was browsing to that file from IE.
What I need to do is browse using http://localhost... so I placed the same file in the www folder under the WAMP directory and then did http://localhost/helloworld.php and it opened up!

But there should be  away I can use files from my desktop instead of placing the files in the www folder...

Comment: Yes there is and no you shouldnt.
Just make a folder favorite out of it and place a shortcut on your dektop.